# How can I avoid this error produced while using 'strict'?

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array, strict

I have a couple of lines of code that work if `use strict;` is commented out.  However, I don't want to have it disabled for the entire script just because of one small section.

I need to either recode it, or somehow disable `use strict;` temporarily and then re-enable it.  The first option is more realistic, but I don't know how to change the code to work in strict mode.

```
my ($ctc_rec_ref) = get_expected_contacts($ctc,$fy);

my @expected_ctc_rec = @$ctc_rec_ref;

print $expected_ctc_rec[0][0]."\n";
print $expected_ctc_rec[0][1]."\n";
print $expected_ctc_rec[0][2]."\n";

sub get_expected_contacts
{
    my (@ctc_rec,$i) = ((),0);
    $STMT = "SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2, field3 FROM table WHERE field4 = ? AND field5 = ? AND field6 = 'E'";
    $sth = $db1->prepare($STMT); $sth->execute(@_); 
    while(@results = $sth->fetchrow_array())
    {
        push @{ $ctc_rec[$i] }, $results[0];
        push @{ $ctc_rec[$i] }, $results[1];
        push @{ $ctc_rec[$i] }, $results[2];

        $i++;
    }   
    return (\@ctc_rec);
}
```

---

With `use strict;` enabled:

> Can't use string ("0") as an ARRAY ref
>   while "strict refs" in use at
>   ./return5.pl line 49.

(line 49: `push @{ $ctc_rec[$i] }, $results[0];`)

With `use strict;` disabled:

```
1468778 
04/01/2011 
30557
```

---

How can I rewrite this code so that it works as if strict mode was disabled?  If that is not possible, can `use strict;` be temporarily disabled and then re-enabled for this short piece of code within the script?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that

```
my (@ctc_rec,$i) = ((),0);
```

doesn't do what you think it does.  It means the same as

```
my @ctc_rec = (0);
my $i;
```

`strict` is doing what it's meant to and catching your mistake. Try writing:

```
my @ctc_rec;
my $i = 0;
```

instead.  That should get rid of the error.

In this case, there's another way to get rid of the error, and simplify your code considerably at the same time:  use [selectall_arrayref](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#selectall_arrayref).

```
sub get_expected_contacts
{
   return $db1->selectall_arrayref(
     "SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2, field3 FROM table WHERE field4 = ? AND field5 = ? AND field6 = 'E'",
     undef, @_
   );
}
```

If you really were intentionally doing something that was prohibited by `strict` (but knew what you were doing), you can disable `strict` locally:

```
use strict;

# this code is strict
{ 
  no strict;
  # some code that is not strict here
}
# strict is back in effect now
```

But you should never do that until you understand exactly what `strict` is complaining about, and why it's ok to do that in this instance.  It's also better to disable only the part of `strict` that you have to.  For instance, you can say `no strict 'refs';` to allow symbolic references without disabling the other things `strict` does.  (Note:  The same technique works with the [warnings](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?warnings) pragma, which you should also be using.)

Comment: thanks a bunch.  this really helped me a lot rather than just provide one solution

Comment: the selectall_arrayref method worked great.  i never knew about that function/method of `DBI` and it looks like it will be very handy in the future

Comment: what's the difference between passing `undef` and leaving `\%attr` out?

Comment: @CheeseConQueso, if you leave `\%attr` out, then the first parameter in `@_` will be treated as `\%attr`.  You can pass an empty hashref instead of `undef`, but you _must_ pass something for `\%attr` if you want to bind placeholders.

Comment: gotcha... that makes sense. They should re-word this or mention what you said in http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.616/DBI.pm#General_Interface_Rules_&_Caveats - it says `In general, you can ignore \%attr parameters or pass it as undef.`

Comment: @cjm Nice solution I wasn't even looking for this but it's pretty cool +1

Answer (score 10):

The problem is with the declaration of @ctc_rec and $i. Try this and your code should stop giving the error from strict:

Replace:

```
my (@ctc_rec,$i) = ((),0);
```

With:

```
my @ctc_rec;
my $i = 0;
```

Comment: thanks - although you did answer first with the working solution, cjm gave me a lot more to consider & work with.